# Is there hope for my fearful, anxious dog?

Tags: training, socializing

I have had my dog since he was 6wks old, he is now 7yrs.  He loves to lay on my lap, touch me, but if I pet, pick him up he acts fearful, like he might bite me, though he never has. I have used calming meds with no success, he has a thunder shirt, he does seem slightly more relaxed with that, slightly.  I would love to be able to cuddle him, but he wants no part of it... Is there any hope?

Answer (score 1):

Many animals are uncomfortable with being picked up and held, even if they're sold about sitting on laps. I know cats who enjoy being tumbled end over end or tossed into the air and caught, but who will want down if you're just holding them for more than a minute or two.

If you're at all nervous (the "might bite me" suggests you might be) the dog may also pick that up, and it won't help.

Personally, I chalk this up to individual personality.

You can *train* a dog or cat to tolerate, and then maybe enjoy, being held. The process is the same as for any other training; make a point of getting them used to the idea, reward patience with praise and a treat or play or extra cuddles of *their* preferred type -- whatever they respond to.

(All cats are uncomfortable with having their paws held.I make a point of getting mine used to it and even making careful paw massage a regular part of our play; it makes ckaw-trimming a bit less of a struggle. There are a few other undignified things I've gotten them used to for similar purposes. It comes down to how willing you are to work with the animal to explain what you want from them.)